# Double integration using Python

Tags: python, math, scipy

I have the following integral (I don't know why the screenshot went so low so you need to scroll a bit).
I tried the following code:

```
from scipy import pi, sqrt
from scipy.integrate import dblquad
func = lambda x,y: ((1-sqrt(x**2+y**2))/(sqrt(x**2+y**2)))*(x**2)
x1,x2 = -1, 1
y1,y2 = lambda x: -sqrt(1-x**2), lambda x: sqrt(1-x**2)
print (dblquad(func, x1, x2, y1, y2))
```

But I keep getting

```
The occurrence of roundoff error is detected, which prevents 
  the requested tolerance from being achieved.  The error may be 
  underestimated.
  **opt)
```

The result I get doesn't seem correct:

```
(nan, 1.0867783627477699e-07)
```

[image]

Comment: I suspect the issue is coming from SciPy evaluating your function at `x = 0`, `y = 0`, where it'll give a `nan`. Try rewriting the function to return `0` in that special case, e.g. with something like `func = lambda x, y: 0.0 if x == y == 0 else ((1-sqrt(x**2+y**2))/(sqrt(x**2+y**2)))*(x**2)`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Thank you, it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integrand of your integral is not defined at the point `(0, 0)`. Mathematically, you end up dividing `0` by `0`. Computationally, `func(0.0, 0.0)` will give a NaN, so if `dblquad` happens to evaluate your integrand at that point, you can expect to get a NaN as a result.

However, the integrand is continuous *near* `(0, 0)`, and has a limit of `0` as `(x, y)` approaches `(0, 0)` from any direction, so it's natural to extend the definition of the integrand to the whole unit disk by specifying that its value at `(0, 0)` is `0`.

So to fix the integration, you can rewrite `func` to special-case the point `(0, 0)`, for example with:

```
def func(x, y):
    if x == y == 0.0:
        return 0.0
    else:
        return (1-sqrt(x**2+y**2))/(sqrt(x**2+y**2)))*(x**2)
```

On my machine, if I make that replacement for `func` and then execute the rest of your code exactly as written, I get the following result:

```
>>> print (dblquad(func, x1, x2, y1, y2))
(0.261799387785821, 1.4745421123040386e-08)
```

And as I'm sure you're aware, it's straightforward to evaluate the integral analytically to find that the value should be π/12. So let's compare the value we got with the expected value:

```
>>> pi / 12.
0.2617993877991494
```

So it looks as though SciPy is giving a result that's accurate to within the desired error bounds.